# MySQL- Improvement on count(*) aggregation with composite index keys

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, aggregation, sql-query-store

I have a table with the following structure with almost 120000 rows,

`desc user_group_report
+------------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| Field            | Type     | Null | Key | Default           | Extra |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+
| user_id          | int      | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| group_id         | int(11)  | YES  | MUL | NULL              |       |
| type_id          | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL              |       |
| group_desc       | varchar(128)| NO|     | NULL              |
| status           | enum('open','close')|NO|     | NULL       |       |
| last_updated     | datetime | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP |       |
+------------------+----------+------+-----+-------------------+-------+`

I have indexes on the following keys :

- user_group_type(user_id,group_id,group_type)
- group_type(group_id,type_id)
- user_type(user_id,type_id)
- user_group(user_id,group_id)

My issue is I am running a count(*) aggregation on above table group by group_id and with a clause on type_id

Here is the query :

```
select count(*) user_count, group_id
from user_group_report
where type_id = 1
group by group_id;
```

and here is the explain plan (query taking 0.3 secs on average):

```
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type  | possible_keys                   | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_group_report | index | user_group_type,group_type,user_group | group_type | 10      | NULL | 119811 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+-------+---------------------------------+---------+---------+------+--------+--------------------------+
```

Here as I understand the query almost does a full table scan because of complex indices and When I am trying to add an index on group_id, the rows in explain plan shows a less number (almost half the rows) but the time taking for query execution is increased to 0.4-0.5 secs.

I have tried different ways to add/remove indices but none of them is reducing the time taken.

Assuming the table structure cannot be changed and querying is independent of other tables, Can someone suggest me a better way to optimize the above query or If i am missing anything here.

PS:
I have already tried to modify the query to the following but couldn't find any improvement.

```
select count(user_id) user_count, group_id
from user_group_report
where type_id = 1
group by group_id;
```

Any little help is appreciated.

**Edit:**

As per the suggestions, I added a new index

**type_group** on (type_id,group_id)

This is the new explain plan. The number of rows in explain,reduced but the query execution time is still the same

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys                   | key     | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_group_report | ref  | user_group_type,type_group,user_group | type_group | 5       | const | 59846 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------------------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+--------------------------+
```

**EDIT 2:**
Adding details as suggested in answers/comments

```
select count(*)
from user_group_report
where type_id = 1
```

This query itself is taking 0.25 secs to execute.

and here is the explain plan:

```
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table            | type | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref   | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_group_report | ref  | type_group       | type_group | 5       | const | 59866 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------------+------+---------------+---------+---------+-------+-------+-------------+
```

Comment: `count(user_id)` is likely to be slower than `count(*)` because it checks `user_id` for being not `NULL`.

Comment: What is the `PRIMARY KEY`?  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, it is more descriptive than `DESC`.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that your `group_type` is wrong. Try to switch the attributes.

```
create index ix_type_group on user_group_report(type_id,group_id)
```

This index is better for your query because you specify the `type_id = 1` in the `where` clause. Therefore, the query processor finds the first record with `type_id = 1` in your index and then it scans the records in the index with this `type_id` and performs the aggregation. With such index, only relevant records in the index are accessed which is not possible with the `group_type` index.

Comment: thanks it did help to reduce number of rows for evaluation but the query execution time is still the same any issue you see ?

Comment: Does it have anything to do with other indices, though i feel its not the issue.

Comment: If the execution time is still the same then there must be some external issue in your environment (network latency?)

Comment: I don't think that's the case as there is no issue with other queries and am directly running this from mysql console.

Answer (score 2):

If type_id is selective (i.e. it reduces the search space significantly), creating an index on `type_id, group_id` should help significantly.

This is because it reduces the number of records that need to be grouped first (remove everything where type_id != 1), and only then does the grouping/summing.

EDIT:

Following on from the comments, it seems we need to figure out more about where the bottleneck is - finding the records, or grouping/summing.

The first step would be to measure the performance of:

```
select count(*)
from user_group_report
where type_id = 1
```

If that is significantly faster, the challenge is likely in the grouping than in finding the records. If that's just as slow, it's in finding the records in the first place.

Comment: thanks. I see the same suggestion from the otehr answer too. Please follow my comment

Comment: I still couldn't improve time though the rows for evaluation reduced to half

Comment: Can you please update your question showing the new query plan and index?

Comment: In that case, it is likely you're running up against a bottleneck elsewhere - have you checked memory, CPU and disk utilization?

Comment: I don't think that's the issue as every other query on other tables and even on the same table is running fine.

Comment: I've updated my answer with the next step if figuring out what's going on. Can you please update your question with the answer?

Comment: Added the details

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190768/discussion-between-neville-kuyt-and-coder-477).

Answer (score 1):

Do most of the columns really need to be `NULLable`?  Change to `NOT NULL` where applicable.

What percentage of the table has `type_id = 1`?  If it is most of the table, then that would explain why you don't see much improvement.  Meanwhile, the `EXPLAIN` seems to be thinking there are only two distinct values for `type_id`, hence it says only half the table will be scanned -- *this number cannot be trusted*.

To get more insight into what is going on, please do these:

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT...;
```

And

```
FLUSH STATUS;
SELECT ...
SHOW SESSION STATUS LIKE 'Handler%';
```

We can help interpret the data you get there.  ([*Here*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#handler_counts) is a brief discussion of such.)